# Using Amazon sns service to send push notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, amazon-sns

I have configured my application to receive push notifications from Amazon SNS. I'm using the library `aws-amplify`. All listeners work normally except `Notifications.Push.onNotificationReceivedInForeground`.

```
import { Notifications, Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

...

const updatedAwsConfig = {
  ...awsConfig,
  oauth: {
    ...awsConfig.oauth,
    urlOpener,
    redirectSignIn: isLocalhost
      ? localRedirectSignIn
      : productionRedirectSignIn,
    redirectSignOut: isLocalhost
      ? localRedirectSignOut
      : productionRedirectSignOut,
  },
  graphql_headers: async () => {
    const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();
    return { Authorization: currentSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken() };
  },
};
Amplify.configure(updatedAwsConfig);
Notifications.Push.enable();
...

useEffect(() => {
    handlePermissions().then();
    const listenerToken = Notifications.Push.onTokenReceived(
      myTokenReceivedHandler,
    );
    const listenerForeground =
      Notifications.Push.onNotificationReceivedInForeground(
        myNotificationReceivedHandler,
      );
    const listenerOpened = Notifications.Push.onNotificationOpened(
      myNotificationOpenedHandler,
    );

    return () => {
      // unsubscribe();
      listenerToken.remove();
      listenerForeground.remove();
      listenerOpened.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

In a background state and in a terminated state everything works as expected. But when the app is in the foreground nothing happens when I send a test message from Amazon SNS. Help me find the reason or explain what I'm doing wrong. sorry for my english I will be grateful for any help

I configured everything according to the AWS Push notification documentation, but it didn’t give anything

Comment: What do you mean with nothing happening? The handler is not called or the handler is not working? Please share also the code of the handler.

Comment: The handler is not called or the handler is not working.

Comment: const myNotificationReceivedHandler = notification => {
    console.log('notification foreground');
    Alert.alert(notification.body);
  };